# Ubuntu 16.04.1 (Xenial Xerus) LTS upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I have a **dual boot computer** with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 8.1. My Ubuntu has recently started notifying me about the 16.04 Xenial Xerus update with an **Upgrade** option. If I upgrade, **will the dual boot remain alright without affecting the GRUB console**? Has anyone tried it out?

Comment: So long as the upgrade goes correctly, you will be okay.

Comment: @Zalgo, have you tried this out on a dual boot computer?

Comment: yes, my main setup is a dual boot with 16.04 and windows 10, for when i cant run something through wine. EDIT: if something _does_ go wrong, running the update-grub command _should_ fix it anyway.

Comment: My upgrade with similar dual boot went without any problems. I think GRUB is updated after every new kernel update, which you should have had plenty if you did regular updates in the past.

Comment: @Valentas, is the Windows partition unaffected?

Comment: No, why would it be? If you are really worried, back up your important data.  The main things that could  possibly go wrong (see other questions in askubuntu) is (1) your upgrade fails and you are unable to boot - then you can copy your data and fresh install using bootable USB or CD. (2) your upgrade is successful but you cannot see windows any more, but you can fix this using tools such as https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. But if you are already using GRUB and you have not manually changed anything in GRUB settings, then this should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

A fresh new install is better and safer than an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the system with bleachbit and ubuntu-tweak and rebooting it before upgrading has always been a safe way for me.